# My App crashing on firebase certain phones

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 12
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "2.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    productFlavors {
        app {
            applicationId "com.app.example"
        }
        app2 {
            applicationId "com.app2.example"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'
    compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:5.9'
    compile 'com.applozic.communication.message:mobicomkit:5.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.cleveroad:loopbar:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.ekimual:croperino:1.1.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    compile 'com.uncopt:android.justified:1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    compile 'com.github.renaudcerrato:static-maps-api:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daasuu:BubbleLayout:1.1.1'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.Kennyc1012:BottomSheet:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.5.0'
}
```

Thats my gradle file, I am getting crash on certain phones.Not all phones. Google Pixel working fine, but someone with samsung 9+ is reporting that my app is crashing.I have checked firebase for errors, and i see the below errors reported.but have no clue how to fix it. PLEASE Help me, if u have faced similar issue. what could this be down too?

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
    No static method zzc(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzv; in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzv; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzv' appears in /data/app/com.app.example-es0Dl2G-gL0904IhfDIX2w==/base.apk:classes9.dex)
    com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd (Unknown Source:197)
com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run (Unknown Source:26)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run (Unknown Source:7)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)


Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
No static method zzac()Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzap; in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzap; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzap' appears in /data/app/com.app.example-1/base.apk:classes9.dex)
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzb (Unknown Source)
com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.onStartCommand (Unknown Source)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:3688)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap23 (ActivityThread.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update `firebase-messaging`

Replace

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
```

To

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```